# Python (Madlibs) react differently to the same code

Tags: python

So I have been learning Python with 'Automate The Boring Stuffs WITH Python', and I stumbled a problem in chapter 8-MadLibs project. I know that my code can't read from file like the question required, as I am want to make sure the core part is functional first. The code I created can detect if the input text has any 'adjectives', 'verb', 'adverb' and 'noun' and replace them with words from user's input, and finally create a text file with these changes. The code has the same lines of code for detecting noun, verb, adverb and adjective.

```
import os
def MadLibs(what):
input_text=str(what)
text=input_text.split()
j=0
for j in range(len(text)-1):
    if text[j].lower()=='adjective':
        adj=input('Enter an adjective:\n')
        text[j]=adj
    elif text[j].lower()=='verb':
        vrb=input('Enter a verb:\n')
        text[j]=vrb

    elif text[j].lower()=='adverb':
        adv=input('Enter an adverb:\n')
        text[j]=adv

    elif text[j].lower()=='noun':
        noun=input('Enter a noun:\n')
        text[j]=noun
    
    
output = ' '.join(text)
textFile=open('D:\\Python\\Automate stuffs with Python\\ch.8 project2 results.txt','w')
textFile.write(output)
textFile.close()
```

However, when I run the code, it can't find 'verb', as the code didn't ask for the replacement word for 'verb'. Can anyone explain why? Here is the result.

```
>>> MadLibs('The ADJECTIVE panda walked ADVERB to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.')
   Enter an adjective:
   s
   Enter an adverb:
   f
   Enter a noun:
   g
   Enter a noun:
   t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing for loop as follows.

```py
for i,j in enumerate( text ):
    if j == 'e':
        text[i] = input('')
```